# How do you find odd elements in an array?

Tags: python, arrays

```
def fillaray(size):

    num = [0] * size
    num = [random.randint(0,9) for i in range(size)]
    print(num)

    return num


def totalOdds(num, size):

    for i in range (size):
        if i % 2 ==0:
            odd = num[i]
            i+1
    print(odd)
```

As you can see in `def totalOdds()`I'm trying to separate the odd elements from the array "num."  I plan on adding all the values in the odd elements up.  Can someone point me in the right direction to what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to add the elements which are odd ? Or elements at odd indices ?

Comment: Your `totalOdds` function.... you don't need to increment `i`; the `for i in range` bit already does that. Your `print` it *outside* of the loop, it will only print one number (the last one).

Answer (score 3):

1. You are not summing them
2. i+1 is doing nothing

to get all odd elements

```
odds = [n for n in nums if n%2]
```

to get only the sum of odd elements

```
sum_odds = sum(n for n in sums if n % 2)
```

Comment: Nice answer but no need for that second set of parens in your `sum`, you can pass `n for n in sums if n % 2` straight to `sum`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the for loop and index being in []. ([n for n in nums if n%2]).  Can you explain to me how that works?

Comment: @user2348621: There is no index, I only loop over all elements. Search for list comprehension

Answer (score 1):

```
nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
odds = [ n for n in nums if n%2 ]
print odds
```

Gives:

```
>>> 
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11]
```

This can be put into a function like so:

```
def getOdds(aList):
    return [ n for n in aList if n%2 ]
```

Example usage:

```
myOdds = getOdds(nums)
print("{0} has {1} odd numbers which were {2}".format(nums,len(myOdds),myOdds))
print("The odd numbers sum to {0}".format(sum(myOdds)))
```

Produces:

```
>>> 
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12] has 6 odd numbers which were [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11]
The odd numbers sum to 36
```

As to what you're doing wrong, you're iterating over an iterable containing the elements `0` to `size` this won't **always** be the value of `num` (unless `num` is indeed `range(size)`). Once you make `i` represent a value in `num` which you're iterating over, `if i%2 == 0` will mean it's **even**, if you want odds, the number **musn't** be divisible by two. Hence this should be changed to either `if i%2 != 0` or `if i%2`. You will also have to declare the `odd` list **before** the `for i ...` loop, so you can append the numbers in `num` which meet the condition in the `if i%2` selection control structure. You should appened the number in `num` by doing `odd.append(i)`, at the moment you're reassigning odd a new value. You also **should not** be incrementing `i`. 'i' should represent a number in `num` not the *index* of the number in `num`.

Answer (score 1):

Can be done in one line:

```
print sum(x for x in num if x & 1)
```

Also, see my comment under the question for where you went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to find the sum of elements at **odd places** in the array :

```
def totalOdds(num, size):

    for i in range(size):
        if i % 2 ==0 :
            odd += num[i]
    print(odd)
```

If you are trying to sum the **odd valued** elements :

```
def totalOdds(num, size):

    for i in range(size):
        if num[i] % 2 !=0 :
            odd += num[i]
    print(odd)
```